# Designing an app that connects to a database

Tags: php, c++, iphone, database

I have made a website (php) and it connects to a database so it can have users and post material. Imagine it like a forum. Now how would I go about making an iPhone app that connects to the same database. I am already teaching myself c++ to make the app, but am not sure how I will connect it to the database.

Answer (score 2):

To do web-based databases, the best practice*** is to use HTTP requests to a PHP script. That way you will not have to establish a database connection from the app, leaving Usernames and Passwords excluded from the actual project. Create some PHP scripts that will do what you need by sending POST and GET variables.

***In my experience and preference

Answer (score 1):

You need to build out API end points for all the actions that are possible.

E.g posts/view   posts/edit   posts/add

A popular and well documented architecture to use would be REST 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer

If you are using a PHP framework there are often helper libraries for creating the API

This tutorial should help you understand it
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/creating-an-api-centric-web-application/

Answer (score 1):

You just setup a [RESTful webservice](http://www.slimframework.com/), then access to it on Obj-C via [Restkit](http://restkit.org/).

EDIT: btw if you haven't got fancy app needs, just [make your website responsive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design) and you'l be done.

Answer (score 0):

I am a newbie to iphone development and have been working on Iphone for a month or so. Would like to give some tips on this:

1) First read up on Objective-C since you are making an Iphone app and how Xcode in general works

2) Next the connecting to the web API, you could use AFNetworking. Here is a [Tutorial](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk_afnetworking/) to get started. You need to know what is the API to get the data.

3) Next you need to parse the data depending whether it is an JSON or XML data from the API. This will allow you to get the data.

4)You can now display in the Xcode using the UI

Answer (score 0):

Your app can connect to your service by issuing HTTP requests to URLs on your server.  You can use whatever backend you like, I have personally used PHP with MySQL since virtually all hosting services will support these tools.   You form queries by defining URLs that perform a function.  Generally, you want to use POST requests when you're changing data on the server, and GET requests when you're making read-only requests for information.

You have to be careful to design your URLs and your server to prevent unauthorized access, I won't describe the details here but the web is full of good advice about this.  I'll focus here on how you connect to your service using URLs.

I recommend using a library that aids in sending requests and receiving responses.  Back (a year or so ago) when I was actively working on an app that did this, I used the AsiHTTPRequest library, which is available for free, but I see now that the author has discontinued support for it.   My $0.02: it worked well for my app: http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/

There are two parts: 1) send request, and 2) receive and process response.  You generally want to make sure your requests are issued asynchronously so that your app doesn't freeze while the request is making its way over the internet, the server processes the request, and you receive the response.

For convenience in parsing the results, have your web app backend send the responses in apple plist format.   Or you could use XML, but I like plist because support for it is baked in to the SDK.

Here's code from my app that does this:

```
// this allows you to switch between the "live" web service and a local development copy
#ifndef _USE_LOCAL_SERVER_
#define kAppCustomerInfoURL @"https://mysite.com/path/to_my/service/"
#else
#define kAppCustomerInfoURL @"http://localhost/path/to_my/service/"
#endif

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:kAppCustomerInfoURL];
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
// udm is my singleton that holds properties for the current user
[request setPostValue:[udm getProperty:kNameProperty] forKey:@"name"];
[request setPostValue:[udm getProperty:kPhoneProperty] forKey:@"phone"];
[request setPostValue:[udm getProperty:kEmailProperty] forKey:@"email"];
[request setPostValue:[udm getProperty:kCityProperty] forKey:@"city"];
[request setPostValue:[udm getProperty:kAddressProperty] forKey:@"address"];
[request setPostValue:[udm getProperty:kDeliveryNotesProperty] forKey:@"comments"];
[request setPostValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u", arc4random()] forKey:@"random"];

[request setValidatesSecureCertificate:NO];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request startAsynchronous];
```

Your object needs to implement the requestFinished: and requestFailed: methods:

```
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    NSString *response = [request responseString];

    NSData* plistData = [response dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSPropertyListFormat format;
    NSString *errorStr;
    NSDictionary* plist = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:plistData 
                                                           mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListImmutable 
                                                                     format:&format 
                                                           errorDescription:&errorStr];
    if ( ! plist ) 
    {
        // NSLog( @"Error: %@", errorStr );
        [errorStr release];
        return;
    }

    for ( NSString *key in [plist allKeys] )
    {
         if ( [key isEqualToString:@"result"] )
         {
              NSString *resultStr = [plist objectForKey:@"result"];
              if ( ! [resultStr isEqualToString:@"ok"] )
              {
                   // set an error
              }
         }
        // more cases 
     }
}
```

Here's my response failed method, it sets some app state and sends a notification that the request has finished, that other parts of the app may use to update themselves upon a request finishing:

```
- (void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    NSError *error = [request error];
    NSLog( @"update customer info failed: %@", [error localizedDescription] );

    self.syncDataToServerOK = NO;

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kUserDataSyncFinishedNotification object:nil];
}
```